# how to use multi model, one controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use three models in one controller
if click  tag '삭제', I want to execute `free_destroy` action in management controller.

When I click the link, this error page occurs:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ManagementsController#free_destroy
>
> and Couldn't find Management with id=1

How can i fix it?
Why does this error occur?

Please answer for me.

**controller**

```
class ManagementsController < ApplicationController
load_and_authorize_resource param_method::params_management
def index
 @users = User.all
 @freemanages = Freemanagement.all
end

def freepost_delete
 @freemanage = Freemanagement.new(params.require(:modal).permit(:content, :title_id))
 @freemanage.save()

 redirect_to :back
end

def secret_delete
 # @secretmanage = Secretmanagement.new(params.require(:modal).permit(:content, :title_id))
 # @secretmanage.save()

 # redirect_to :back
end

def show
 freemanage = Freemanagement.find(params[:id])

 redirect_to freemanagements_path(freemanage), method: :delete
end

def free_destroy
 freemanage = Freemanagement.find(params[:id])
 freemanage.destroy()

 redirect_to freepost_path(freemanage.title_id), method: :delete
end

def refuse_freepost
 freepost = Freepost.find(params[:remodal][:title_id])
 freemanages = Freemanagement.all
 freemanages.each do |freemanage|
   if (freemanage.title_id.to_i != freepost.id)
     next
   else
     freemanage.destroy()
   end
 end
 redirect_to :back
end

def  refuse_secretpost
end
end
```

**index.html**

```
<head>

</head>
<body>
 <header>
   <!-- 공지사항 작성 글 -->
   <%= link_to '익명겟', secretposts_path %>
   <%= link_to '자유겟', freeposts_path %>
   <%= current_user.last_name + current_user.first_name %>
 </header>
 <section>
   <% @users.each do |user| %>
     <%= user.uid %>
     <%= user.first_name %>
     <%= user.last_name %>
     <%= user.roles_name%>
   <% end %>
 </section>
 <section>
   <% @freemanages.each do |freemanage| %>
     <%= link_to '게시글보기', freepost_path(freemanage.title_id) %>
     <%= freemanage.content %>
     <a href='/freemanagements/<%= freemanage.id %>/delete'>삭제</a>
     <br />
   <% end %>
 </section>
 <section>
   <!-- 익명게시판 관련 게시글 섹션 -->
 </section>
 <script>
 </script>
</body>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
# For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

root 'homes#index'

resources :freeposts do
  resources :free_comments
end

resources :secretposts do
  resources :secret_comments
end

resources :free_comments
resources :secret_comments

get '/managements' => 'managements#index'
get '/freemanagements/:id' => 'managements#show'
post '/freemanagements' => 'managements#freepost_delete'
get '/freemanagements/:id/delete' => 'managements#free_destroy'
post '/freemanagements/refuse' => 'managements#refuse_freepost'
post '/secretmanagements' => 'managements#secretpost_delete'

get 'login', to: redirect('/auth/google_oauth2'), as: 'login'
get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'
get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
# get 'home', to: 'home#show'
# get 'me', to: 'me#show', as: 'me'
end
```

Comment: What about trying controller inheritance in some aspect?

Comment: did you say 1:N relations?

Comment: I suggest as per his heading, But I could not get why it look for Management id if code is looking for Freemanagement id

Comment: how to get Freemanagement id ...?

Comment: I am clear with your approach, if you provide links which goes same controller for all 3 models, you should pass parameter as type so you can distinguish which model you are choosing. And of course, link must go for id which is present in database otherwise you will get this error.

Comment: thanks for your answer, @ray but i can't understand this issue...

Comment: See you finding record by `freemanage = Freemanagement.find(params[:id])` So it depends on how your structure is for, example default scope or whether you have `Freemanagement < Management`, by **STI**  Also check for default scope. Hoping id passed in url is present.

Comment: but, Freemanagement model is not related with Management model.
they, just use one controller.

Comment: So check error log properly, because you need to find where it is written `Management.find(params[:id])`, check log

Comment: if i forcibly added Management model, did't occur error...but why this happening?@ray